# How to stop multiple file attachment in SharePoint list item attachment?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-list

I want to restrict user from uploading multiple attachments in SharePoint list NewForm or EditForm. User should able **to attach/upload only 1 file**.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question so we can help you? you mentioned CSOM, can you share some code or tell us what you did?

Comment: no need CSOM code , required SharePoint c# managed code or jsom

Comment: You can use event receiver for that. ItemAttachmentAdding event receiver. Reference: http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/prevent-user-from-attaching-an-attachment-when-creating-a-new-item-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an event receiver on the list with **ItemAttachmentAdding** event.

Put below code in your event method:

```
 public override void ItemAttachmentAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAttachmentAdding(properties);

        try
        {
            SPAttachmentCollection attachments = properties.ListItem.Attachments;
            if (attachments.Count >= 1)
            {
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot add more than one attachment.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        }    
    }
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: What Happened? Is there any problem in the code? If its useful to you, then kindly accept this answer. So it will be useful to others.

Comment: I can't get a attachment count so that's why code is not execute properly.

Comment: I have updated code. I have tested it. Its working properly.