# Can we prevent attaching more than one attachment file to a custom list item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, custom-list, attachments, item-attachment

I have a custom list inside a SharePoint modern communication site, and i want to prevent attaching more than one attachment per list item? is this possible through UI,power-shell or development?

Now i already read this similar article @ [How to stop multiple file attachment in SharePoint list item attachment?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202201/how-to-stop-multiple-file-attachment-in-sharepoint-list-item-attachment) but this will not work in remote event receivers, as in RER we can not access the `properties.ListItem.Attachments`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant ootb list attachments? Sharepoint list form can be done with some custom forms then from there you can limit the no of attachments by validating on form submit. But if you meant the OOTB form unfortunately there is no way to limit it.

But, you can do a post process where a workflow will run after a list is updated / created removing the excess attachments, workflows via SharePoint designer workflow(spd wf), nintex, msflow will do.

Let me know if the concept helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the Attachments field in a custom form only. First, you should design a custom form either with [Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-and-sharepoint/) or a 3-rd party tool e.g. [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/). Once the form is ready, use what the platform offers for validating field values.

Since I'm working with Plumsail Forms really closely, I can recommend it and even [the solution of a very similar problem](https://community.plumsail.com/t/attachments-field-is-empty/8600).